# Modify view property on button press and hold

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have two views, v1 and v2. My goal is, when the user presses and holds v1, v2 expands using an animation. When the user lets go of v1, v2 stops expanding.

This is what my onCreate looks like:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    root = findViewById(R.id.root);
    shape = findViewById(R.id.shape);

    root.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    isExpanding = true;
                    expandView(shape);
                } return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    isExpanding = false;
                    shrinkView(shape);
                } return true;

                default: return false;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

For expandView() and shrinkView(), I tried adding a while loop containing isExpanding and adding an animation in there:

```
private void shrinkView(final View view) {
    while (!isExpanding) {
        view.animate().scaleXBy(0.1f).scaleYBy(0.1f);
    }
}
```

I also tried changing the LayoutParams inside the loop:

```
private void expandView(final View view) {
    while (isExpanding) {
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        currWidth = layoutParams.width;
        currHeight = layoutParams.height;
        currWidth = +GROWTH_FACTOR;
        currHeight = +GROWTH_FACTOR;
        layoutParams.width += currWidth;
        layoutParams.height += currHeight;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        view.invalidate();
    }
}
```

but both of these block the ui thread as expected.

Comment: Ui thread gets blocked because of the infinite loop

Comment: @AbhishekPatel correct, hence why I need help :)

Answer (score 1):

Well for this type of animation I would use ObjectAnimator to scale the X and Y. Then I would add a listener to that ObjectAnimator and check in onAnimationEnd if the user is still pressing (isExpanding). As the code below :

```
    View v2 = findViewById(R.id.v2);//lets say u have v2 and v1
       final ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v2, "scaleX", 0.5f);
    final ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v2, "scaleY", 0.5f);
    scaleDownX.setDuration(1000);
    scaleDownY.setDuration(1000);


    final AnimatorSet scaleAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
    scaleAnimation.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);
    scaleAnimation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            if (isExpanding) {
                scaleAnimation.start();
            }
        }
    });


           findViewById(R.id.v1).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    isExpanding = true;
                    if (!scaleAnimation.isRunning()) {
                        scaleAnimation.start();
                    }

                }
                return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    isExpanding = false;
                    scaleAnimation.cancel();
                }
                return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but it didn't work :/ my view didn't change at all!

Comment: updated the answer.. setOnTouchListener instead of setOnKeyListener and play is to define the set while .start() is to start it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use an asynctask that calls its publish method every fixed time interval, in that call expand v2. This will free your ui thread to listen for the release of v1.

Or another approach is to start a thread when user holds v1 and get that thread to `post` back updates (modify v2). Also you can then terminate the thread when v1 is released.